# getting the height of a div to match the width when it shrinks responsively

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, grid-layout

In the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/H3VW5/ I have 3 divs where the width is based on perencentage. Is there a simple way (without having an image in it) to get the height to match a certain aspect ratio so that when the window shrinks the height shrinks with the width to keep the same shape? IE. if the div size was `600px x 600px` at `60%` and the window shrunk to make the width `500px` the height would also shrink to `500px`?

```css
/*CSS:*/

.div1 {width:60%; height:400px; background-color:#066; float:left}
.div2 {width:20%; height:400px; background-color:#09F; float:left;}
.div3 {width:20%; height:400px; background-color:#C00; float:left;}
```

```html
<!--HTML:-->

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div) which may solve it for you.

Basically, you let the width just be `auto` (don't specify a px height), and use `padding-bottom` with a percentage (%). Neat.

Comment: Except I had to put a div inside the one that was 60% so that the width could be 100% then the padding would correspond ie. if the padding-bottom was 100% as well it would stay a square.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a `height` and `width` on your `body` and `html`, and then changing the height of your `div` to percentages? This allows you to then set relative liquid heights on your `div` because now they have something to size to.

```
body, html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

.div1 {width:60%; height:40%; background-color:#066; float:left}
.div2 {width:20%; height:40%; background-color:#09F; float:left;}
.div3 {width:20%; height:40%; background-color:#C00; float:left;}
```

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sTT7z/)

Comment: With this method if they don't shrink the browser proportionally the aspect ratio of the div does not stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to control the height of the divs

```
$(".ratio" ).each(function () {
    var height = $(this).width();
    console.log(height);
    $(this).css('height',height + 'px');
});
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/gwx6y/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came with. The only thing which is not hacky and it gets nice aspect ratiou keeping is an image. So, if change the markup a bit to:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="bigimage.jpg" />
    <div class="div1">a</div>
    <div class="div2">b</div>
    <div class="div3">c</div>
</div>
```

and set *max-width: 100%;* to the image its height will be changed like that so it keeps the original aspect ratio. So, we can use that and position the divs absolutelly, set the proper width and height to 100%. The dimensions of the image are leading here. The wrapper takes the same size and because the divs are childs of the same  wrapper their height is also the same.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:60%;
    background-color:#066; 
    z-index: 2;
}
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 60%;
    width:20%; 
    background-color:#09F;
    z-index: 3;
}
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 80%;
    width:20%; 
    background-color:#C00;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Example of my solution is available here:
http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/H3VW5/3/

P.S. The good thing in this approach is that you can keep whatever ratio you want. All you have to do is to create an image with that ratio.